# TYPO3 SOLR Cookie fe_typo_user

Tags: solr, typo3-7.6.x

When I integrate the plugin of SOLR (extension version 6.5.1), and then call the website, the cookie "fe_typo_user" is created. How can I prevent this?

TYPO3 v7.6

Comment: The `fe_typo_user` is only set when session data is needed. Are you testing this in a clean incognito mode browser that you haven't logged in to the interface with?

Comment: There is no login on the page.

Comment: No, but the cookie gets set when a session is started, so if you've logged in to the admin interface yourself, then the cookie will remain set.

Comment: I have not logged in anywhere. It is only when the Solr plugin is used.

Comment: It seems the Solr plugin [uses the session support in Typo3](https://github.com/TYPO3-Solr/ext-solr/search?q=session&unscoped_q=session). My guess is that you're not going to get around that, unless there's some configuration option available (I couldn't find anything from reading the source briefly)

Comment: You could try [switching the last searches mode](https://github.com/TYPO3-Solr/ext-solr/blob/cdeb3a400dd131f0d5aa9e6a10df0e08a58ca86e/Documentation/Configuration/Reference/TxSolrSearch.rst#lastsearchesmode) and disable the last searches completely.